# How to change the Modules "Modules" folder name?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel Modules

https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules

[image]

This is the Folder Structure with Modules.

Is there any way to change it? Like I want to create

Admin\Category

Means my Modules folder name will be Admin

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
      "App\": "app/",
      "Modules\": "Admin/",
      "Database\Factories\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\Seeders\": "database/seeders/"
   }
},
```

I tried with this but not working!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documentation of package yes you can.

First step run this command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Nwidart\Modules\LaravelModulesServiceProvider"
```

Second Step in Config/laravel-modules.php will find ["Modules path","Modules assets path","Default Namespace"] you can customize them

Last Step in composer.json

```json
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
      "App\": "app/",
      "Admin\": "Admin/",
      "Database\Factories\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\Seeders\": "database/seeders/"
   }
},
```

then run composer dump-autoload